# MySQL multi update keeping the order of IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update the precalculated order of items in a MySQL table in this way

```
SET @order_item := 1;
UPDATE item
SET item_order := (@order_item := @order_item + 1)
WHERE
id IN (8,2,1,10);
```

My expected result is:

```
id, item_order
8,  1
2,  2
1,  3
10, 4
```

but as MySQL uses PRIMARY KEY index in id to perform the update, I get:

```
id, item_order
1,  1
2,  3
8,  3
10, 4
```

I am wondering if you guys know any workaround to face this problem and keep MySQL using the index in a single update. I happen just do it by performing a lot of UPDATES in a PHP bucle. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know MySQL very well but does `order by FIELD(id,8,2,1,10)` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ordering it like this.

```
SET @order_item := 1;
UPDATE item
SET item_order := (@order_item := @order_item + 1)
WHERE
id IN (8,2,1,10)
order by FIELD(id,8,2,1,10);
```

Comment: Never used function `FIELD()`. Learned something today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can append an `ORDER BY` clause to your `UPDATE` query to tell MySQL the order you want it to process the rows. Of course, you need to be able to `SELECT` the rows in the desired order using the same `ORDER BY` clause.

But I guess the order is just what you want to achieve :-(

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The order is precalculated by an algorithm and can't be processed in MySQL.

Comment: You can also use `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '8,2,1,10')` but I think @Fred's solution is faster (for several items it doesn't really matter, you'll see the difference on thousands of items).